# Docusign API: How to configure auto navigation

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to set the auto-navigation for my envelope to "Navigate all fields" as explained here

https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-auto-navigate-or-skip-past-optional-fields-such-as-check-boxes-or-radio-buttons#options

The documentation for envelopeDefinition and signer states that field "autoNavigation" is a string, if I try to set something difference then true or false i get error <<"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Boolean value expected for parameter: autoNavigation">>

As experiment I tried to set autoNavigation=false but did not see any difference.

Is the auto-navigation policy something that can be set only via the Admin console for the entire account?

Answer (score 0):

Once an Administrator changes the Auto-Nav feature, it affects all envelopes sent from that Account. Nothing further is needed by the Senders; Signers will interact with Envelopes sent from that account per the chosen setting.

If the Administrator checks the box next to the feature "Allow senders to override" as shown in the below snapshot, this option allows senders to disable the signing auto-navigation option for envelopes they send.

[image]

Once above checkbox is selected, then at an envelope level you can set autonavigation to be turned on or off. The property and its value is "autoNavigation": true or "autoNavigation": false